# Using HTTP REST API to connect 3d game character to a Watson Assistant

Tags: rest, watson-assistant

My goal is to use a Watson Assistant to drive the conversations of a 3d game character in a virtual world. I was able to obtain a bearer token in the game environment from my Watson Assistant through an HTTP REST API call. Now I want to talk to the 3d game character and expect replies which are originating from the Watson Assistant. Is there an example I could look at that describes how this can be done through purely HTTP REST communications?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the functionalities exposed by the API via HTTP request or by using a library depending on your implementation. You can find out more information regarding the API in here: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1 . You should take a look on the **message** API endpoint - this should help you communicate with the Watson Assistant dialog skill, after you create the content.